# Как сделать анимированную гармошку в стиле metro?

Tags: jquery

вот в таком стиле, чтобы при наведении курсора она сворачивалась
[image]

Comment: Мне кажется, что это Flash. Ссылку можно на сайт с примером?

Comment: http://metro-webdesign.info это фреймворк для создания сайтов в стиле метро.
а по своему вопросу уже сам сделал

Comment: Как, если не секрет?

Answer (score 1):

Этом можно легко сделать.Здесь все подробно описано+примеры
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/18/3d-thumbnail-hover-effects/